# Do not run two timers at the same time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I developed a button with two states (Start and Stop).

When I start on one of the lines, a time count is started. When executing the button on a different line (start to start counting on another line), I want to pause the line that was previously active and start the timer on that new line.

My problem is that I am not able to implement this.

When I try to stop the previous line and start only on the new line, the timers simply stop :(

Can someone help me?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdwe3e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**ts**

```
startTimer(data) {
  let self = this;
    self.taskService.startTimer(data);
    self.currentState = self.taskService.getCurrentState();

      const pauseIds = [];
    this.data.forEach(d => {
      if (d.id !== data.key.id && d.idUser !== data.key.idUser
        && this.taskService.fetchDisplay() !== undefined
        && this.taskService.currentState === 'start')
        pauseIds.push(d.id);
    });
    pauseIds.forEach(id => {
      console.log (id)
      this.taskService.pauseTimer(id);
    });

  }

  pauseTimer(data) {
   let self = this;
    self.taskService.pauseTimer(data);
    self.currentState = self.taskService.getCurrentState();

  }
```

**service**

```
startTimer(data) {
    this.time = 0;
    this.currentRowIndex = data.rowIndex;
    this.currentState = 'start';
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.time++;
      } else {
        this.time++;
      }
      this.display = this.time;
      return this.display;
    }, 1000);   
  }

  pauseTimer(data) {
    this.currentRowIndex = data.rowIndex;
    this.currentState = 'pause';
    this.time = 0;
    clearInterval(this.interval);


  }

  fetchDisplay() {
    return this.display;
  }

  getCurrentState() {
    return this.currentState;
  }
```

Comment: You have too many global variables you need to check ur logic. The problem is there. If you remove the line  pauseIds.forEach(id => {
      console.log (id)
      this.taskService.pauseTimer(id);
    }); your code will work almost as you would expect

Comment: Mike, I've seen 4 of your questions on SO now. In which you've removed 3. Can you stop removing them? It's not the point of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ivan Mihaylov mentioned in the comments the logic really seems too convoluted.

Nevertheless the solution is rather simple.

- You should start you timer after you pause all other possible started timers. Otherwise you timer state is `pause` after `startTimer` finishes so conditions in the template prevent active state from displaying.
- You need to reset `display` as well as `time` in `taskService.startTimer` method. Otherwise displayed time at the start contains the last value of previous counter.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcux5n) is a fixed StackBlitz example.